# WebBluetooth APIにて21文字以上のデータをmicrobitへ送信できない

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

### 概要

WebBluetooth APIを用いたBLE通信を介して、ブラウザ上(HTML&javaScript)からmicro:bit(MakeCode)にデータを送る際に、何故か21文字(終端文字含む)以上のデータをmicro:bitに送ることができず、困っています。

### 検証

ブラウザ側のコードの全文はこちらです。
https://gist.github.com/henjin0/1ce1c386311a8ad14fd83b8dbbaee35e

下記のコードを変更することでデータを送信する量を変更することができます。

```js
// これがNG 20文字＋終端（#）
// const text_data_encoded = textEncoder.encode('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#');
// これはOK 19文字＋終端（#）
const text_data_encoded = textEncoder.encode('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa#');
```

### 結果

NGパターンで検証すると、下記の結果が得られます。本来であれば、下記の文字数を減らしたパターンと同じものが得られてほしいと考えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

文字数を減らすと下記のようにエラーなく送信できます。
また、後述のmicro:bitのLED点灯（一瞬だけ赤が入り、緑色になる）も確認できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

micro:bitに関しては下記のプログラムが書き込まれています。なお、set All RGB...ブロックに関しては事前に単独動作することを確認しているほか、20文字送信時について点灯していることは確認してます。
また、Android端末からBLEScannerという検証アプリを用いてデータを送信した際には文字数に関わらずLEDの点灯ができていることから、Makecode側の不具合は考えづらいと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

おそらくWebBluetooth APIに関する事象かなと考えているのですが、21文字以上のデータをBLE経由で送る知見や情報があればご共有願いたいです。

### 各種環境

以下に実施した際の環境をまとめます。

#### PC環境

- Windows 11 Home 22H2
- Google Chrome バージョン: 120.0.6099.199（Official Build） （64 ビット）
- Live Server v5.7.9
- Bluetooth コア仕様 5.2

参考にしたページ:
[PC に搭載されている Bluetooth のバージョンを確認する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/pc-%E3%81%AB%E6%90%AD%E8%BC%89%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-bluetooth-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-f5d4cff7-c00d-337b-a642-d2d23b082793)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### micro:bit環境

- V2.21
- Bluetooth 5.1 with Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE)
- Makecode
- 拡張機能としてBluetoothとMotionbitをインストール済み

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決、というわけではありませんが結論が出ました。
WebBluetooth APIのwriteValueWithoutResponseメソッドでは20byte(半角英数20文字)に制限されてしまうみたいです。加えて、下記リンクのWed, Jun 1, 2022, 1:01 AM GMT+9 の投稿を見る限り、修正が断念されてしまったと見えています。

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1073311&fbclid=IwAR2q5QaDT8E7yaesP2ZLlSoBJ9Gi50K1k2mlvMN0vbEBy5WCA1wti6K6xr8

一発で20byte以上を送るためにはWebBluetoothではない手段を検討するしかなさそうです。。

Answer (score 4):

Bluetooth LEの規格で最低限保証されている、一度に送受信できるアトリビュートのパケットデータサイズ**ATT_MTU** (Attribute Maximum Transmission Unit) は23バイト（23オクテット）です。
（詳しくはBluetooth Core Specificationの「§5.2 LE L2CAP INTEROPERABILITY REQUIREMENTS」に記載されています）

- https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-1/
- https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-2/

Write Without Responseの場合、そのうち3バイトは予約されているので、デフォルトではATT_MTU - 3 = 20バイトのアプリケーションデータを一度に送信できることになります。
（詳しくはBluetooth Core Specificationの「§4.9.1 Write Without Response」に記載されています）

- [Bluetooth Low Energyのデータ通信プロトコルの基本 - フィールドデザイン](https://fielddesign.jp/technology/ble/blespec_protocol/)

ATT_MTUは機器によって異なり、またセントラル／ペリフェラルがサポートしている値のうち小さいほうが使用されます。
Exchange MTU RequestによってクライアントからMTUの拡張をリクエストすることができますが、両機器がサポートしている値が上限となります。
（詳しくはBluetooth Core Specificationの「§4.3.1 Exchange MTU」に記載されています）

AndroidのBluetooth LE APIには[`BluetoothGatt.requestMtu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt)というメソッドがあり、これを使うとアプリケーションからExchange MTU Requestを発行できますが、Windows版のWeb Bluetoothバックエンドに使われているWinRT Bluetooth LE APIは、現状アプリケーションによるExchange MTU Requestの発行に対応していません。通信セッションにおけるMTUの値を取得したり、変更通知イベントを受け取ったりすることのみがサポートされています。Mac/iOSのCore Bluetoothもほぼ同様です。

- [GattSession.MaxPduSize Property (Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile) - Windows UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattsession.maxpdusize)
- [GattSession.MaxPduSizeChanged Event (Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile) - Windows UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattsession.maxpdusizechanged)

Windows側がセントラルになるとき、接続成功時にOSによって自動的にMTUのネゴシエーションが実行され、セントラルとペリフェラルがともに23バイトよりも大きなATT_MTUをサポートしていれば、MTUが拡張されます。

`GattSession.MaxPduSize`プロパティのリファレンスには以下のように書かれていますが、これは[`GattCharacteristic.WriteValueAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.writevalueasync)または[`GattCharacteristic.WriteValueWithResultAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.writevaluewithresultasync)と[`GattWriteOption.WriteWithoutResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattwriteoption)によるWrite Without Responseには当てはまらないと思われます。

> The Windows operating system automatically fragments down larger protocol data unit (PDU) sizes sent to a remote device (wherever supported by the Bluetooth GATT/ATT spec). So under normal circumstances, there's no need for you to know the maximum transmission unit (MTU) size at the application layer if your application's goal is just to send data efficiently.
>
> You can send large amounts of data, and it will be fragmented automatically by the OS using the MTU. Your application is not limited by the MTU size as to the data transfer of each packet.

MTUのサイズによらず可変長のデータを送りたい場合、アプリケーション側で20バイト以下に分割して各パケットにシリアル番号を付けるなどして送信するか、あるいはBluetooth Core Specificationの「§4.9.3 Write Characteristic Value」や「§4.9.4 Write Long Characteristic Values」に記載されているように、書き込みリクエストとレスポンス（コールバック）の往復を伴うWrite With Responseを使う必要があるはず。

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749934/how-to-write-large-amount-of-text-to-write-characteristic

WinRTの場合は[`GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattwriteoption)であり、Web Bluetoothの場合は[`BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic.writeValueWithResponse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic/writeValueWithResponse)メソッドが該当するのでは？

いずれにせよ、一発で簡単にMTUのサイズを超えるデータを送ることはできません。

Bluetoothはバックエンドとなる下位レベルAPIの標準化が全然なされておらず、OSごとに対応度も全然違うので、Web Bluetoothのように共通化された比較的上位側のAPIは最大公約数的な機能しか実装できず、情報も集まりにくいと思います。
まずは各プラットフォームのネイティブAPIと公式サンプルを試しつつ、Bluetooth LEの仕様に習熟したほうがよいかと。
C#やC++/WinRTであれば、async/awaitが使えるので、JavaScriptのasync/awaitと似たような形で非同期処理を書けます。

- https://github.com/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE

Comment: コメントありがとうございます!もともとのBLEの仕様上難しい、という話ですよね。加えて、下の回答先リンクにもある通り、writeValueWithResponseも同様の事象が発生しています。話に出ている20byteを超えたあとの往復もWebBluetooth APIの関数内で解決できていればよかったのですが。。

Comment: 一般的なプラットフォームでアクセスしたWebページからBLEを操作できることが今回要件だったこともあり、ネイティブでの実装は見送りつつwriteValueWithResponseで20byteごとに再送する形がベストですね。

Comment: 上記について語弊が出そうだったため補足します。上記２件のコメントにあるwriteValueWithResponseはWebBluetooth APIのメソッドを指します。

Comment: @InoueMinoru [BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothRemoteGATTCharacteristic)の`writeValueWithResponse()`と`writeValueWithoutResponse()`は、[WriteCharacteristicValue()](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#writecharacteristicvalue)に渡す`response`引数が違うだけで、「レスポンス有り」すなわち`response`が`"required"`の場合「Use the Write Characteristic Value procedure.」と書かれてあります。「Write Long Characteristic Values」を実行してくれる上位レベルのAPIになるわけではないため、結局データを分割して、レスポンスが返ってきた後に次のパケットを送信する操作をアプリケーション側で繰り返す必要があるはず。ただしWeb Bluetoothの場合、レスポンスがどのような形で返ってくるのか不明です（`Promise`の完了？）。

Comment: @InoueMinoru 現状のWeb Bluetoothは発展途上の実験的な技術であり、Bluetooth LE仕様に関する基本的な知識がない状態で触るのはまったくお勧めしません。機能の不十分なAPI、分かりづらいドキュメント、サンプルコードの不足など、課題が山積みで、アプリケーションで問題が起きたときに原因を特定するのが非常に困難になることが予想されます。一見遠回りでも、まずはプラットフォームのネイティブAPIを使ってBluetooth LEの作法を学習することをお勧めします。各プラットフォームのAPIを使っている開発者のほうが圧倒的に多く、特にiOSやAndroidに関してはノウハウも蓄積されていて情報が集まりやすいからです。